# Быстрая сортировка Хоара

Tags: сортировка

Как реализовать алгоритм быстрой сортировки без медианного элемента?

Answer (score 3):

Медианный элемент - это лишь один из способов выбора значения-разделителя (pivot),
такая эвристика для уменьшения вероятности (но не полного исключения) плохого разбиения.

Сортировка будет работать и при использовании произвольного элемента - первого, последнего, среднего по индексу, или со случайным индексом.

Выбор первого или последнего не очень хорош, если массив уже сортирован (или почти сортирован) - нередкий случай, для других методов выбора разделителя вероятность плохого массива невелика.

Comment: @Daniyar В ответе что-то непонятно?

Comment: Если я буду каждый раз буду использовать рандом для pivot, то это не будет считаться медианным элементом?

Comment: Нет, выбор медианы из трёх и выбор случайного индекса - разные методы.

Comment: Мне нужна по заданию нужна Быстрая сортировка
Хоару (без медианного
(pivot) элемента). Если я выберу pivot = arr[random], это будет по заданию?

Comment: Pivot - это разделительный элемент. А его выбор может быть через медиану, случайным или другим способом. Что препод имел в виду - сказать трудно, т.к. QuickSort - сортировка, основанная на сравнениях. Но есть разновидности, например, поразрядная быстрая сортировка, однако гадать на кофейной гуще я не буду, нужно уточнить у того, кто задавал.