# Определить внешний радиус не взвешенного неориентированного графа методом обхода в ширину

Tags: графы

Какой примерный план реализации кода этой задачи:
Определить внешний радиус не взвешенного
неориентированного графа методом обхода в ширину.
(Внешним радиусом графа будем называть наибольшее среди
кратчайших расстояние от центра до какого-либо узла. )
Вывести значение, а также соотвтуетсвующие ему цепи.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно найти центр этого графа, а потом найти кратчайший маршрут по алгоритму Дейкстры?

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201008/) нужно принять ответ галочкой, если он понятен.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, Дейкстра тут ни при чём.

Выполняем поиск в ширину (BFS) из каждой вершины S. Получаем  таблицу расстояний от всех вершин. Находим строку, максимальное значение в которой минимально по сравнению с другими строками. Она соответствует центру графа С, то самое значение - радиус графа R.

Выполняем ещё один поиск в ширину из С. Находим самую удалённую от неё вершину U.
При втором обходе нужно записывать предшественника для каждой вершины, тогда после нахождения U разматываем предшественников до C (на R шагов) - это и есть нужная цепь.

Comment: первый раз - это поиск в ширину.

Comment: второй раз - обход в ширину?

Comment: Это одно и то же